# Deriving SDE for process with two uncorrelated Brownian motions and factor

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

Derive SDE for the following 2 dimentional process

$Y(t) =  wX_1(t) + \sqrt{1-w^2}X_2(t)$

where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are brownian motions with drifts and brownian increments

$dX_1(t)= \mu_1dt + \sigma_1dW_1(t)$

$dX_2(t)= \mu_2dt + \sigma_2dW_2(t)$

I can do a taylors series expansion to get the SDE but not sure how to include the factors in the resulting SDE.

Also what values of $w$ will make this a martingale? I guess I need to choose $w$ such that the drift part of the SDE becomes $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every $a_1$ and $a_2$,
$$
Y(t)=a_1X_1(t)+a_2X_2(t)
$$
is
$$
Y(t)=\mu t+Z(t),
$$
where
$$
\mu=a_1\mu_1+a_2\mu_2,\qquad Z(t)=a_1\sigma_1W_1(t)+a_2\sigma_2W_2(t).
$$
(This is algebra.) Furthermore, if $W_1$ and $W_2$ are two independent standard Brownian motions, then
$$
Z(t)=\sigma W(t)
$$
for some standard Brownian motion $W$ and
$$
\sigma^2=a_1^2\sigma_1^2+a_2^2\sigma_2^2.
$$
In particular, $Y$ is a martingale if and only if $\mu=0$, that is, in your case, if and only if
$$
w\,\mu_1+\sqrt{1-w^2}\,\mu_2=0.
$$
Note finally that if $W_1$ and $W_2$ are simply *uncorrelated*, not *independent* as above, then strange things could happen.

Comment: Thanks. This was very useful. On your last remark, in a normal distribution doesnt non-correlation and independence go hand in hand?

Comment: The latter implies the former but not the other way round unless one asks that the vector is **jointly** normal (assumption not in your question).